# Attempting to write protractor e2e test for theme selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, protractor

I am new to Protractor and finding this a little difficult, I hope i can explain it and if you require any further information please let me know.

So.. The app i am working on has a Default theme set to Black, there is then a drop down you can select in the navbar which gives you an option to select a different theme "White", I have been able to select the White theme successfully but i would like to know how to use this if the default theme were to be white or changed to white and then check that the theme Black is still working how could i write the e2e test to reflect that.

I should mention that once a theme is selected it is then cached for 1 year so that theme remains unless changed.

Code i have written to select Light theme

```
it('should select theme selector', () => {
         let top = element(by.css('cloudgate-theme-selector'));
         top.element(by.css('.dropdown-toggle')).click();
         element(by.cssContainingText('li a', 'Light')).click();
         browser.sleep(1000);
     });
```

Thank you for your help in advance.
cheers,

Comment: So you probably want to check that switching from one theme to other and validating whether correct theme is displayed ? Is it your scenario ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am trying to validate, but unsure as to how to write that up! thanks Kishan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We too Have dark theme and light theme:
You probably need to find the value where the themes are stored.

In my Project see the below html code:

> For Dark theme:

```
<body class="nsweb-theme-dark">
<nsw-app _nghost-ewh-1=""><toaster-container _ngcontent-ewh-1="" ng-reflect-toasterconfig="[object Object]">
```

> For Light Theme:

```
<body class="nsweb-theme-light">
<nsw-app _nghost-ewh-1=""><toaster-container _ngcontent-ewh-1="" ng-reflect-toasterconfig="[object Object]">
```

SO you can just Take the text where theme data(For me it is class) is available i.e. light/dark and then validate it with:

```
if (theme == dark)
  {
   expect(themecolor).toBe("nsweb-theme-dark")
  }
else 
  {
   expect(themecolor).toBe("nsweb-theme-light")
  }
```

Hope you are clear. :-)

Comment: OMG thanks so much Kishan you are a legend, that makes perfect sense i will apply this and let you know. Thank you once again my friend you have been awesome.